# Could you please sort out this Excel filter formula?

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula

I have sample data as shown below. I want to return the names of the **three/two oldest players** from the **year 2010** and **Team Arizon**a.

I stored the data in a worksheet named ***_master***. I used this formula, but it returns an error:

```
=FILTER(_master,(_master[Year]=2010)*(_master[Team]="Arizona")*(_master[Age]>=LARGE(_master[Age],3)))
```

| Year | Team | NAME | No. | Pos | Ht | Wt | Age | Exp | College | FirstName | LastName | Ft | In | Inches | NumGrp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2009 | New Orleans | D'Juan Woods | 84 | WR | 6-1 | 210 | 25 | 1 | Oklahoma State | D'Juan | Woods | 6 | 1 | 73 | 80-89 |
| 2009 | New Orleans | Usama Young | 28 | CB | 6-0 | 200 | 24 | 3 | Kent State | Usama | Young | 6 | 0 | 72 | 20-29 |
| 2009 | Arizona | Gabe Watson | 98 | DT | 6-4 | 329 | 26 | 4 | Michigan | Gabe | Watson | 6 | 4 | 76 | 90-99 |
| 2009 | Arizona | Jason Wright | 31 | RB | 5-10 | 212 | 27 | 5 | Northwestern | Jason | Wright | 5 | 10 | 70 | 30-39 |
| 2009 | Arizona | Karlos Dansby | 58 | LB | 6-4 | 250 | 28 | 6 | Auburn | Karlos | Dansby | 6 | 4 | 76 | 50-59 |
| 2009 | Arizona | Reggie Wells | 74 | G | 6-4 | 312 | 29 | 7 | Clarion | Reggie | Wells | 6 | 4 | 76 | 70-79 |
| 2009 | New Orleans | Darnell Dinkins | 80 | TE | 6-4 | 260 | 32 | 8 | Pittsburgh | Darnell | Dinkins | 6 | 4 | 76 | 80-89 |
| 2009 | Arizona | Adrian Wilson | 24 | S | 6-3 | 226 | 30 | 9 | North Carolina State | Adrian | Wilson | 6 | 3 | 75 | 20-29 |
| 2009 | Arizona | Will Davis | 59 | LB | 6-2 | 261 | 23 | R | Illinois | Will | Davis | 6 | 2 | 74 | 50-59 |
| 2009 | Arizona | Beanie Wells | 26 | RB | 6-1 | 228 | 21 | R | Ohio State | Beanie | Wells | 6 | 1 | 73 | 20-29 |
| 2010 | Arizona | Jeremy Clark | 71 | DT | 6-3 | 309 | 26 | 1 | Alabama | Jeremy | Clark | 6 | 3 | 75 | 70-79 |
| 2010 | Arizona | Calais Campbell | 93 | DE | 6-8 | 290 | 23 | 2 | Miami (Fla.) | Calais | Campbell | 6 | 8 | 80 | 90-99 |
| 2010 | Arizona | Levi Brown | 75 | OT | 6-5 | 324 | 25 | 3 | Penn State | Levi | Brown | 6 | 5 | 77 | 70-79 |
| 2010 | New Orleans | Jermon Bushrod | 74 | OT | 6-5 | 315 | 25 | 3 | Towson | Jermon | Bushrod | 6 | 5 | 77 | 70-79 |
| 2010 | New Orleans | Jeff Charleston | 97 | DE | 6-4 | 265 | 26 | 3 | Idaho State | Jeff | Charleston | 6 | 4 | 76 | 90-99 |
| 2010 | Arizona | Ben Claxton | 62 | C | 6-2 | 301 | 29 | 3 | Mississippi | Ben | Claxton | 6 | 2 | 74 | 60-69 |
| 2010 | New Orleans | Reggie Bush | 25 | RB | 6-0 | 203 | 24 | 4 | USC | Reggie | Bush | 6 | 0 | 72 | 20-29 |
| 2010 | New Orleans | Marques Colston | 12 | WR | 6-4 | 225 | 26 | 4 | Hofstra | Marques | Colston | 6 | 4 | 76 | 10-19 |
| 2010 | New Orleans | Jammal Brown | 70 | OT | 6-6 | 313 | 28 | 5 | Oklahoma | Jammal | Brown | 6 | 6 | 78 | 70-79 |
| 2010 | Arizona | Ralph Brown | 20 | CB | 5-10 | 185 | 31 | 10 | Nebraska | Ralph | Brown | 5 | 10 | 70 | 20-29 |
| 2010 | New Orleans | Kendrick Clancy | 71 | DT | 6-1 | 305 | 31 | 10 | Mississippi | Kendrick | Clancy | 6 | 1 | 73 | 70-79 |
| 2010 | New Orleans | Dan Campbell | 89 | TE | 6-5 | 265 | 33 | 11 | Texas A&M | Dan | Campbell | 6 | 5 | 77 | 80-89 |
| 2010 | New Orleans | Mark Brunell | 11 | QB | 6-1 | 217 | 39 | 17 | Washington | Mark | Brunell | 6 | 1 | 73 | 10-19 |
| 2010 | New Orleans | Jonathan Casillas | 52 | LB | 6-1 | 227 | 22 | R | Wisconsin | Jonathan | Casillas | 6 | 1 | 73 | 50-59 |
| 2010 | New Orleans | Chase Daniel | 10 | QB | 6-0 | 218 | 23 | R | Missouri | Chase | Daniel | 6 | 0 | 72 | 10-19 |
| 2017 | Arizona | Kelvin Beachum | 68 | OL | 6-3 | 308 | 33 | 11 | Southern Methodist | Kelvin | Beachum | 6 | 3 | 75 | 60-69 |
| 2017 | New Orleans | Ian Book | 16 | QB | 6-0 | 206 | 24 | 2 | Notre Dame | Ian | Book | 6 | 0 | 72 | 10-19 |
| 2017 | New Orleans | Zack Baun | 53 | LB | 6-3 | 225 | 25 | 3 | Wisconsin | Zack | Baun | 6 | 3 | 75 | 50-59 |
| 2017 | Arizona | Eno Benjamin | 26 | RB | 5-9 | 207 | 23 | 3 | Arizona State | Eno | Benjamin | 5 | 9 | 69 | 20-29 |
| 2017 | Arizona | Victor Bolden | 38 | WR | 5-8 | 178 | 27 | 3 | Oregon State | Victor | Bolden | 5 | 8 | 68 | 30-39 |
| 2017 | Arizona | Breon Borders | 21 | CB | 6-0 | 189 | 27 | 4 | Duke | Breon | Borders | 6 | 0 | 72 | 20-29 |
| 2017 | Arizona | Darrell Baker Jr. | 31 | CB | 6-1 | 190 | 24 | R | Georgia Southern | Darrell | Baker Jr. | 6 | 1 | 73 | 30-39 |
| 2017 | New Orleans | Josh Black | 57 | DT | 6-3 | 290 | 24 | R | Syracuse | Josh | Black | 6 | 3 | 75 | 50-59 |
| 2022 | Arizona | Andre Baccellia | 82 | WR | 5-10 | 175 | 25 | 1 | Washington | Andre | Baccellia | 5 | 10 | 70 | 80-89 |
| 2022 | New Orleans | Kawaan Baker | 87 | WR | 6-1 | 215 | 23 | 1 | South Alabama | Kawaan | Baker | 6 | 1 | 73 | 80-89 |
| 2022 | New Orleans | Paulson Adebo | 29 | CB | 6-1 | 192 | 23 | 2 | Stanford | Paulson | Adebo | 6 | 1 | 73 | 20-29 |
| 2022 | Arizona | Zach Allen | 94 | DE | 6-4 | 281 | 24 | 4 | Boston College | Zach | Allen | 6 | 4 | 76 | 90-99 |
| 2022 | Arizona | Stephen Anderson | 89 | TE | 6-2 | 230 | 29 | 5 | California | Stephen | Anderson | 6 | 2 | 74 | 80-89 |
| 2022 | Arizona | Budda Baker | 3 | S | 5-10 | 195 | 26 | 6 | Washington | Budda | Baker | 5 | 10 | 70 | 0-9 |
| 2022 | New Orleans | Josh Andrews | 68 | G | 6-2 | 298 | 31 | 7 | Oregon State | Josh | Andrews | 6 | 2 | 74 | 60-69 |
| 2022 | New Orleans | Kiko Alonso | 47 | OLB | 6-3 | 239 | N/A | R | Oregon | Kiko | Alonso | 6 | 3 | 75 | 40-49 |
| 2022 | Arizona | Marcell Ateman | 84 | WR | 6-4 | 215 | N/A | R | Oklahoma State | Marcell | Ateman | 6 | 4 | 76 | 80-89 |

Comment: i was download from this [link](https://www.contextures.com/tablesamples/sampledatafootballplayers.zip)

Comment: what error do you get? Have you tried evaluating your formula step by step (formula group in the ribbon / evaluate)

Comment: "_master" need to be the name of your table, not the sheet. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/rename-an-excel-table-fbf49a4f-82a3-43eb-8ba2-44d21233b114

Comment: If you want to use `LARGE()` then you have to apply the primary logics within it otherwise, it bring only the oldest age of everyother team members. See i have posted using `FILTER()` & `AGGREGATE()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `SORT()` & `TAKE()` function one can accomplish the desired output:

[image]

---

```
=TAKE(SORT(FILTER(A2:P43,(B2:B43="Arizona")*(A2:A43=2010)),8,-1),3)
```

---

Or, Using `Structured References` aka Tables

```
=TAKE(SORT(FILTER(_master,(_master[Team]="Arizona")*(_master[Year]=2010)),8,-1),3)
```

---

However, if you don't have `TAKE()` function then using `AGGREGATE()`

```
=FILTER(_master,
  (_master[Year]=2010)*
  (_master[Team]="Arizona")*
  (_master[Age]>=AGGREGATE(14,6,_master[Age]/((_master[Year]=2010)*(_master[Team]="Arizona")),3)))
```

---

Comment: Reading the question I see a bit of confusion using tables. Your formulae might be working, however probably not provide the information OP needs.

Comment: @MátéJuhász using `LARGE()` it simply wont get as it is supposed to be. Using `SORT()` & `TAKE()` makes much easier!

Comment: if i want nth age for e-g 2nd oldest people

Comment: For only second oldest then : `=CHOOSEROWS(SORT(FILTER(_master,(_master[Team]="Arizona")*(_master[Year]=2010)),8,-1),2)`

Comment: @YaserArafath till here you get all the sorted list from z to a : `SORT(FILTER(_master,(_master[Team]="Arizona")*(_master[Year]=2010)),8,-1)` now from here you can extract the one you need. Using `INDEX()` or `CHOOSECOLS()` or if you top oldest then use `TAKE()` as shown